# CPU and RAM operations in different application states

Tags: memory, cpu

This will actually consist of multiple questions.

1. After an application is started and loaded into the RAM the RAM's operations are refreshed many times a second (even without any input and the application just sitting on the screen). Is this correct? If so, how come the data is not stored in a static state like in HDD?
2. Does the CPU still run operations on the application, even when there are no instructions coming from it?

Comment: I think you might need to do a little bit more reading on what the functions of the CPU and RAM are. It will also probably help to look at some [beginner programming info](http://www.codecademy.com/) to understand how an application uses RAM.

Comment: The RAM refreshing is a hardware provision totally unrelated to what is in that RAM. The internal RAM circuitry that does that has no knowledge of the outside world (and does not care). Neither does the OS know anything about the RAM circuitry.

Answer (score 3):

> "Does the CPU still run operations on the application, even when there
>   are no instructions coming from it?"

CPUs perform instructions as they cycle, some instructions taking multiple cycles, others can be executed in parallel, the CPU clock speeds up and slows down as needed depending on what instructions and how many  of them are being sent, without instructions they idle untill new instructions are sent.

> "After an application is started and loaded into the RAM the RAM's
>   operations are refreshed many times a second (even without any input
>   and the application just sitting on the screen). Is this correct? If
>   so, how come the data is not stored in a static state like in HDD?"

If the application changes a variable, then that information will be updated in memory as necessary. Beyond that RAM gets refreshed to preserve the integrity of the information due to RAM's volatility, storing information on the HDD(through virtual memory, or swap partition) is used often, but not preferred due to low read/write speeds.

Comment: RAM (hardware) has no concept of a stack or heap, those are merely parts of a process' memory space (software), dependent on the runtime, and not even necessarily in RAM. Also, your definitions for stack and heap are incorrect, I could just as easily store data in the stack.

Comment: @Bob The RAM(RAM in this case being memory allocated to a program, not hardware) used by a program holds a stack and a heap, since he asked from a software perspective I answered in a software perspective. You could quite easily store data in the stack as memory addresses happen to be data, but storing other information in the stack(aside from being pointless in standard computing) isn't contextually related and wouldn't add to the answer.

Comment: How is storing data in the stack "pointless in standard computing"? When you declare an `int` (or any other local variable) in C, where do you think it's stored? The heap is *only* used for dynamic allocations (`malloc`) and global vars (in C).

Comment: @Bob Well I can hardly be blamed for having a CS teacher who refuses to put anything in a context beyond Java.

Comment: Even in Java, it's not correct - [Java primitives are stored in the stack too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061692/1030702). But, in any case, the abstracted perspective of a Java program running in the JVM is not applicable to all other software, which is not tied to a specific programming language (that being said, C is probably the closest you'll get to how the OS and hardware handles it, unless you want to go directly to assembly.) (Thanks for the edit - +1 now.)

Comment: @Bob I never said a Java application running under the JVM was applicable, according to a CS professor teaching classes at a college ranking 16th in the world in the degree, memory addresses are stored in the stack and point towards the heap. As this happens to be wrong, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also, for modern CPUs it's not so simple as one instruction per cycle per thread. Some instructions take multiple cycles, and with pipelining for example, multiple instructions can be executed per cycle.

Answer (score 2):

> After an application is started and loaded into the RAM the RAM's operations are refreshed many times a second (even without any input and the application just sitting on the screen). Is this correct?

Right.

Old computers such as the Commodore 64 would need to halt the CPU during this process (in the case of the Commodore 64, the video chip actually handled RAM refresh).

Modern computers have dedicated memory controllers that issue DRAM refreshes.

> If so, how come the data is not stored in a static state like in HDD?

There is such a thing as Static RAM.  The cache in a CPU uses it.  It's much more expensive and power-hungry (and quicker due to not needing refresh cycles) than DRAM, so it tends to be used only where the benefit outweighs the cost.

On old 486 motherboards, when cache RAM started becoming a thing, you had sockets where you were expected to populate with small static RAM chips.  These were not addressable as main RAM but external CPU cache (386/486 era).  Then, the cache RAM started being included on a card with the CPU (Pentium I/II era), then built into the CPU.

> Does the CPU still run operations on the application, even when there are no instructions coming from it?

Intel CPU's have a `HLT` instruction that tells it to stop until the next interrupt.  An interrupt can come from a device or other sources (a reset is a type of interrupt).  Old CPUs did not physically halt when they encountered this instruction but later ones will physically power down.

CPUs that do not have such an instruction never stop.  The only way to get them to do nothing is place them in an endless loop.

Comment: Incidentally, older OSes (including Windows 95/98 and DOS) never issued `HLT` instructions. This becomes apparent if you run them in a VM with hardware virtualisation - you'll see one CPU core pinned at 100% even though nothing from that era should max out a modern CPU while idling. That's because they sit in a busy loop (spinwaiting). There are third-party TSRs (background processes from a bygone era) that will issue endless `HLT`s at low priority, so whenever nothing else is doing anything the CPU powers down a bit. Modern OSes do this automatically.